# как ввести с консоли дробное число с bufferreader

Tags: java, ввод

как ввести с консоли дробное число с bufferreader

Comment: ...через точку?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский да, например 9,5

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понимаю, чем отличается ввод текста от ввода дроби...

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String text=br.readLine();

double number=Double.parseDouble(text);  //если не число будет Exception
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже сам нашёл, задачу решил)

Comment: извините, мне кажется, что это плохой ответ. что если в строке будет два вещественных числа? имхо лучше обернуть в `Scanner` и использовать `nextDouble`